# Why there are no job running on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Using hadoop1.3.0. I ran the example WordCount correctly in eclipse. But when I enter localhost:50030, it said running jobs and retired jobs were both none. The truth was I had already gotten the correct output. Did I do something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not run map-reduce programs from eclipse. You need to create a runnable jar of it and run it from a separate VM using hadoop command.

May be you can use : `hadoop jar runnable.jar inputHDFSPath outputHDFSPath`

Comment: Well, I have done what you said. But unfortunately the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, running a job from eclipse doesn't submit it to your job tracker, but spawns a standalone VM instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you had run the command correctly, then there should be no running job or retired job. This is what it indicates. Why are you expecting the completed job to be under retired jobs or running jobs category ? 
**As the job has completed successfully, it must be present under completed jobs list.**

Comment: But there are no completed jobs list showing on the page, only running and retired jobs. I also tried the command line with "hadoop job -list", still couldn't see any job.